# Popups only work on specific pages

Tags: bug, stack-exchange-button

**Update**

I have realised that the two "edit" links on my Preferences page (to edit favourite and ignored tags) can't be clicked either. Checking the Web Developer>Network activity, I can see the following messages:

[image]
[image]

---

**Original Post**

The popup you get when cliking on the stackexchange icon or when hovering on your user name have stopped working a few weeks ago on some pages.

For example, it works on these pages:

- https://stackoverflow.com/tags
- https://stackoverflow.com/users

But it does not work on those pages:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions
- https://stackoverflow.com/

I'm using Firefox 23 on Windows 7 (just upgraded to Firefox 23.0.1 but same behaviour). The behaviour started a few weeks ago, on 3 different PCs.

The popups I'm talking about:

[image]

And:

[image]

Comment: Check the JavaScript console, see what error you get. Also check the loaded resources.

Comment: Also clear your browser's cache, you never know.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I've done that already.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Do you know how to do that on Firefox? I have opened the Error Console but it does not show anything when I try to open those popups.

Comment: @assylias Firefox menu --> Web Developer --> Network. You'll probably see some JS resources failing to load.

Comment: It looks fine when I load http://stackoverflow.com/ but does not change when I click on the stackexchange button (i.e. it does not show new resources being loaded). When I look at the console tab, nothing happens when I click on the stackexchange button either (it behaves as if it were disabled).

Comment: "Too much recursion"? Stack Overflow is overflowing the stack? Oh, the irony.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clearing cache, cookies etc. did not do anything.

In the end I uninstalled/reinstalled firefox and that solved the problem.